# How to call a function from models.py to views or template

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am a beginner in Django and Python. I am creating a Payroll project whose calculations are done using a function from models.py. The user must input the variables through templates and save it to sql. Then  search for the employee (through templates again) and output his payroll details. That is the time when I want to use the calculation function.

Data from the database is working and is outputted by the templates. As for the calculated data, it simply isn't showing.

I have been trying to use the function to no avail and I've searched for 3 days already. I am at lost at what to do now.

models.py

```
from django.db import models 

#Class in model.py acts as a table in database
class Add_Employee(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField (max_length = 150, default = '', null = False)
    position = models.CharField (max_length = 150, default = '', null = False)
    email = models.EmailField (max_length = 150, default = '', null = False)
    address = models.CharField (max_length = 500, default = '', null = False)
    basic_pay = models.FloatField(default=None) 
    overtime_hours = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    allowance = models.FloatField(default=None)
    days_leave = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    other_deductions = models.FloatField(default=None)


    #Django admin page; the table will show the name
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}{}'.format(self.name, self.position, self.email, self.address)

    def salary_calculation(self):

        #Earnings
        self.overtime_hours_pay = self.overtime_hours * 64 

        self.gross_income = self.basic_pay + self.overtime_hours + self.allowance

        #Deductions
        self.days_leave = self.days_leave * 512
        self.pagibig = self.basic_pay * 0.01
        self.gsis = self.basic_pay * 0.09
        self.withholdingtax = self.basic_pay * 0.15
        self.philhealth = self.basic_pay * 0.0275 / 2

        self.total_deductions = self.days_leave + self.pagibig + self.gsis + self.withholdingtax + self.philhealth

        #Net Pay
        self.net_pay = self.gross_income - self.total_deductions

        print ("Calculated.") #this was never outputted from all the times i tried.
        return (self)
```

views.py

```
#Code for form submission and redirect back to employer page again
def add_employee_form_submit(request):
    print ("Form is successfully submitted.") #print can only be seen on the terminal, not the browser


    #create local variable for each variable entered using the form
    name = request.POST["name"]
    address = request.POST["address"]
    email = request.POST["email"]
    position = request.POST["position"]
    basic_pay = request.POST["basic_pay"]
    overtime_hours = request.POST["overtime_hours"]
    allowance = request.POST["allowance"]
    days_leave = request.POST["days_leave"]
    other_deductions = request.POST["other_deductions"]

    #assigning the local variable into the database fields
    employee_info = Add_Employee(name = name, address = address, email = email, position = position, basic_pay = basic_pay, overtime_hours = overtime_hours, allowance = allowance, days_leave = days_leave, other_deductions = other_deductions )

    #save the entire stuff
    employee_info.save()

    return render(request, 'employer.html')


def search_employee_form_submit(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_id = request.POST['search_id']
        
        if search_id:
            employee_match = Add_Employee.objects.filter( pk = search_id ) #pk is primary key
            
            if employee_match:

                return render (request, 'employee.html', {'Search': employee_match})
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'No results found.')

        else: 
            return HttpResponseRedirect('employee/')

    return render(request, 'employee.html')
```

employee.html (template for query and result viewing)

```
    <h1>Employee Payroll</h1>
    <br><br>
    <h2>Enter your ID:</h2>
    <form action="/search_employee_form_submit/", method="post"> <!--it will use 'search_employee_form_submit' url after submitting form-->

        {% csrf_token %} <!-- added for privacy reasons/security-->
        <br>
        <input type = "text" name="search_id" placeholder="Enter employee id">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="search employee">
    </form>
    <br><br>

    <!-- Code for when your search has results / employee -->
    {% if Search %}
        {% for k in Search %}
            Name: 
            {{ k.name }} <br>
            Position:
            {{ k.position }} <br>
            Email: 
            {{ k.email }} <br>
          ..... etc (this part is working)

            Overtime Hour Pay:
            {{ k.overtime_hours_pay }}<br>
            Gross Income:
            {{ k.gross_income }}<br><br> 
          ..... etc (calculated data = doesnt show result)
        {% endfor %}
```

Pardon me for the long post as I have no idea where I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are referencing fields that do not exist in the model, such as `overtime_hours_pay` and `gross-income`. If you do `self.someFieldName` on a model instance, that field should be defined or inherited in the model. So this is wrong:

```py
self.overtime_hours_pay = self.overtime_hours * 64
```

You could either

- Add those fields in the model definition
- Remove the `self` part and make them normal variables. Which would look like:

```py
def salary_calculation(self):
        overtime_hours_pay = self.overtime_hours * 64 

        gross_income = self.basic_pay + self.overtime_hours + self.allowance

        self.days_leave = self.days_leave * 512
        pagibig = self.basic_pay * 0.01
        gsis = self.basic_pay * 0.09
        withholdingtax = self.basic_pay * 0.15
        philhealth = self.basic_pay * 0.0275 / 2

        total_deductions = self.days_leave + pagibig + gsis + withholdingtax + philhealth

        net_pay = gross_income - total_deductions

        return net_pay
```

After doing that, you could calculate net_pay in the view.

```py
...
if employee_match:
    # calculation
    net_pay = employee_match.salary_calculation()
    # then pass this to the template
    return render (request, 'employee.html', {'Search': employee_match, 'net_pay': net_pay})
else:
    messages.error(request, 'No results found.')
```

Comment: I see. I had the wrong idea about the ```self``` part in Classes. Thank you very much! It has solved my problem!